# Java Swing change colorscheme

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, darkmode

I am currently developing a larger application and I want to be able to use a dark mode.

I am using the Look and Feel:
`UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`

I do not want to use the Nimbus look and feel because i think it does not look good. Can i just change the default colors of this look and feel?

I have already tried around a lot by doing

```
Color control = UIManager.getColor("control");
Color info = UIManager.getColor("info");
Color text = UIManager.getColor("text");
UIManager.put("control", control);
UIManager.put("info", info);
UIManager.put("text", text);
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(textEditor.getFrame());
```

But that didn`t work either.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: *"I am using the Look and Feel: `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`"* The system look and feel is at least three different PLAFs. Which OS are you viewing it on? BTW - If I wanted to offer the user a dark PLAF, I'd source a 3rd party PLAF that offers that.

Comment: I am using WIndows, but this application is part of a bigger project which will need to run on any platform. Also i cannot use any libraries to keep the filesize down.

Comment: I chose this way of choosing the system LOF to make sure the app blends in with the os. It does not need to look the same everywhere, i just want a dark/ lightmode on every device.

Comment: Is there any way of manually editing the colors?

Comment: *"Is there any way of manually editing the colors?"* Sure. Implement it in a custom PLAF. But as others have already done that, why reinvent the wheel?